# What can be said about a non-square matrix that does not have any left/right/both inverses

Tags: matrices, inverse

It is common knowledge that a square matrix is singular iff its determinant is $0$. Can anything be said about a non-square matrix that does not have any left/right/both inverses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No left inverses $\iff$ not injective $\iff$ rank $<$ number of columns.

No right inverses $\iff$ not surjective $\iff$ rank $<$ number of rows.